# JS RegExp capturing parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex

I am a newbie to JS RegExp. I got confused by the following RegExp matches.

`var x = "red apple"`

`var y = x.match(/red|green/i)`

Now `y` is `["red"]`.

However if I add a pair of parentheses around `red` and `green` and make y to be

`var y = x.match(/(red|green)/i)`

Now, `y` would become `["red", "red"]`. I have searched online https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp
and found that it's something called
*capturing parentheses*.

It says `For example, /(foo)/ matches and remembers 'foo' in "foo bar." The matched substring can be recalled from the resulting array's elements [1], ..., [n] or from the predefined RegExp object's properties $1, ..., $9.`

But I don't understand what does it mean by `recalled from the resulting array's element or from predefined RegExp object's properties`?  Can anyone please explain ? Thank you!

Comment: Try to use the global search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the match result (*obtained from the* [**capturing group**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html)) can be accessed by referring to that specific group number `[1]` .. `[n]` where `n` represents the number of the capturing group you want to access.

**Note:** `[0]` applies to the overall match result.

```
var r = 'red apple'.match(/(red|green) apple/i);
if (r)
    console.log(r[0]); //=> "red apple"        # entire overall match
    console.log(r[1]); //=> "red"              # match result from 1st capture group
```

Answer (score 1):

When the match result is stored to (in this case) `y`, `y[0]` is always the *overall match*, while `y[1]` .. `y[9]` contain the individual capturing groups.

In `/(red|green) apple/`, applied to `"This is a red apple."`, `y` will be `["red apple", "red"]`.

Comment: Thanks for your brief but awesome solu!

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
var y = x.match(/(red|green)/gi);
```

Answer is

```
y = ["red"]
```

Comment: The question is not about how to match but asking for explanation on capturing group